# Why can't I access my server (running XAMPP on Ubuntu) remotely?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, xampp

I've been developing locally on a little Ubuntu netbook with XAMPP for about 7 months. Two weeks ago, I got a computer I'd like to use as a server. I've installed the latest Ubuntu distribution and XAMPP, moved all my files over, and forwarded port 80. I've also got a domain name from dyndns.com which is being updated by a client which runs in my router (a Netgear WGR6154 v8).

Now, when I try to access my server by typing in the address I got from dyndns.com, the browser loads until it times out. I can access everything locally using localhost as the address so I believe XAMPP is running, just unable to connect with the internet.

Also, in httpd.conf `Listen` directive is set to: `Listen 80`

`netstat -a` output removed (dead link).

In order to be able to view my files over the internet what should I do next?

Comment: output of ifconfig posted here: http://pastebin.com/m35895c8b

Comment: check that your portforwarding works, everything else seems to be ok

Comment: have you tried other services? try forwarding ssh and connecting to it from outside (beware of any security risks with this)

by the way, you should use 'netstat -a --inet' so that sockets dont get displayed.

Comment: Also, general question: I was under the impression that using a service like dyndns.com took the place of a static ip address and that a static ip usually cost extra from your isp. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your router isn't letting you connect to your own IP address?

Did you try checking from an external client?  If you don't have one available, you can use an open proxy like [nobodycanstop.us](https://nobodycanstop.us/) to test it.

Comment: Sadly, a tree limb fell and knocked out my cable so the server is off line for 2 more days. I'll report back when it's up again.

Comment: Alright! Back up and running! When I use the address dyndns.com gave me with nobodycanstop.us I get a message that it couldn't connect with the host

Comment: Okay, this means that the problem isn't local and that nobody can connect to your server.

Comment: Current update: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7991743#post7991743

Comment: Also, I get lots of popups when I use nobodycanstop.us, to the point of sometimes breaking firefox. Just thought I'd give you a heads up...

Comment: @danwoods -- Just use Adblock Plus!